# Terms For "Onvalid" JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, validation

So, I'm trying to make a form that validates with client-side validation first. With this validation, if the input is invalid, I add a class that is styled with CSS. I do this with JQuery:

```
$('input').on('invalid', function() {
    $(this).addClass('invalid'); // This class is already defined in CSS
    $(this).removeClass('valid'); // Take out the class that is for valid inputs
});
```

And the above works just fine. But, I want the same sort of thing to happen on a valid response. I have tried the following:

```
$('input').on('valid', function() {
    $(this).addClass('valid'); // Already defined in CSS as well
    $(this).removeClass('invalid'); // Take out the invalid class
});
```

I am not sure why it is not working, but maybe my syntax is incorrect, or maybe JQuery doesn't have a `on('valid')` function. Thanks in advance, and any response is appreciated!

Comment: `invalid` is a standard JavaScript event, it has nothing to do with jQuery. There's no corresponding `valid` event.

Comment: So, that means in JavaScript, there is no `document.getElementByTagName('input').onvalid = function()` function? Didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: That's correct.